# Why is ffmpeg output video contrast / brightness too bright?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, flowplayer, hls.js

I have a .mov file which I run through `ffmpeg` to create HLS segments / chunks. However, when I playback the HLS video it is too bright.

For a sanity check, I ran the same .mov video file through the [FlowPlayer](https://flowplayer.com) processing pipeline and the results were the same, the output video is too bright!

I have a number of videos. Most do not have this problem but some (and only some) of the .mov files exhibit this issue.

A broken video stream reports (see below for full output):

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/arib-std-b67), 1920x1080, 8507 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
```

A working video stream reports (see below for full output):

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, 45457 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
```

Is this something to do with `hevc v h264` (whatever they mean)?

Incidentally, I am using the native HTML5 video player in conjunction with [hls.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hls.js) to playback the videos.

How do I fix this?

Here is my `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i "rgb.mov" \
  -v warning -preset ultrafast -g 59.96 -sc_threshold 0 \
  -map 0:0 -map 0:0 \
  -s:v:0 1920x1080 -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 4521k \
  -s:v:1 1920x1080 -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 7347k \
  -var_stream_map "v:0 v:1" \
  -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -f hls \
  -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_playlist_type vod \
  -hls_segment_filename "hls/v%v/chunk%d.ts" "hls/v%v/index.m3u8"
```

And here are some screenshots showing the original video in comparison to the output video.

ORIGINAL:

[image]

OUTPUT:

[image]

For the problem video `ffmpeg -i "rgb.mov" -hide_banner` gives:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'rgb.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2021-08-03T11:23:40.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: 3.594173
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +51.5483+000.1628+000.459/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 12 Pro
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 14.7.1
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2021-08-03T12:23:40+0100
  Duration: 00:00:54.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8730 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/arib-std-b67), 1920x1080, 8507 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-08-03T11:23:40.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      DOVI configuration record: version: 1.0, profile: 8, level: 4, rpu flag: 1, el flag: 0, bl flag: 1, compatibility id: 4
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 172 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-08-03T11:23:40.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2[0x3](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-08-03T11:23:40.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:3[0x4](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-08-03T11:23:40.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:4[0x5](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 34 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-08-03T11:23:40.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
At least one output file must be specified
```

For a working video `ffmpeg -i "rgb.mov" -hide_banner` gives:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'rgb.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2021-12-01T10:53:47.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: 4.785777
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +51.5485+000.1627+012.533/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 12 Pro
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 14.8.1
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2021-12-01T10:53:47+0000
  Duration: 00:00:36.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 45692 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, 45457 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-12-01T10:53:47.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : H.264
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 188 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-12-01T10:53:47.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2[0x3](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-12-01T10:53:47.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:3[0x4](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-12-01T10:53:47.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:4[0x5](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 34 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-12-01T10:53:47.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Your source video is HDR. You'll have to tonemap it to SDR.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, any pointers or links on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=hevc) explains that:

> The High Efficiency Video Coding (HEVC) compression standard is a video compression format intended to succeed H.264

and further reveals that browser support for HEVC is currently very poor.

@Gyan comments that:

> Your source video is HDR. You'll have to tonemap it to SDR.

Now I assume @Gyan knows it HDR based on the fact that its using HEVC. This [article](https://uk.pcmag.com/tvs-home-theater/71182/what-is-hdr-high-dynamic-range) explains HDR (High Dynamic Range) and talks in detail how it impacts brightness, color and contrast.

Finally, this [article](https://www.maxvergelli.com/how-to-convert-hdr10-videos-to-sdr-for-non-hdr-devices) explains that HDR looks bad - e.g. brightness, contrast and color issues - on devices that do not support HDR. Thankfully it also gives an `ffmpeg` fix by using this filter:

```
-vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,format=yuv420p
```

Adding this flag to my existing `ffmpeg` command did the HDR to SDR (Standard Dynamic Range) conversion / tonemap, making it work on Chrome and fixing my problem.

NOTE: Detecting HDR is an issue in its own right so I won't cover that here but please refer to [this link](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/22059/how-to-identify-hdr-video)